# jQuery transition animation not occurring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make effect that will make previous quote dissapear and new quote to appear when I click on button, but with nice transition effect.

In the code below I tried with jQuery .animate and opacity property but it just inserts new quote without any animation effects.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var $body = $('body');
    var $h1 = $('h1');
    var $innerhtml = $('.innerhtml');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    $body.css('background', color);
    $h1.css('color', color);
    $innerhtml.css('color', color);

    var link = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rat395/9de1f8ad52f53170f90d9d8a204ee9ad/raw/e3ba3cf835cba8ecf8fa8da1e513bb40059f9355/quotes.json';
  
    $.getJSON(link, function(data) {

      var random = data[Math.floor((Math.random() * data.length) + 1)];
      $innerhtml.animate({ //Here is the problem, its not working
          opacity: 0
        }, 500,
        function() {
          $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, 500);
          $(this).html('<p>"' + random[0] + '"</p>' + '<br>' + random[1]);
        });
    })
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  transition: all ease-in-out 1.5s;
}

.innerhtml {
  transition: all ease-in-out 1.5s;
}

.flex {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
}

.text-in {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  height: 40px; 
}

.innerhtml {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerhtml"></div>
    <div class="buttons">

      <button class="btn btn-default off"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"</span></button>
      <button class="btn btn-default quote">New quote</button>
      
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
.innerhtml {
  transition: all ease-in-out 1.5s;
}
```

to

```
.innerhtml {
  transition: color ease-in-out 1.5s;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/edxn2frq/

Answer (score 0):

Added `.toggleClass()` to the body and `.innerhtml`

```
$body.css('background', color).toggleClass('act die');
$innerhtml.css('color', color).toggleClass('act die');
```

Then defined the two classes: `.act` and `.die` as follows:

```
 body.act {
    background: currentColor;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1.5s;
  }
  body.die {
    background: currentColor;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1.5s;
  }

.innerhtml.act {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all linear 2s;
}
.innerhtml.die {
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: all linear 1s;
}
```

The property `transition` needs the actual properties to be in the same ruleset so it knows what to animate. Since you have a variable color property, I used `background:currentColor`. There's also some changes in the basic layout so now there shouldn't be any jumping.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(function() {

  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var $body = $('body');
    var $innerhtml = $('.innerhtml');
    var color = '#';
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    $body.css('background', color).toggleClass('act die');
    $innerhtml.css('color', color).toggleClass('act die');
    var link = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rat395/9de1f8ad52f53170f90d9d8a204ee9ad/raw/e3ba3cf835cba8ecf8fa8da1e513bb40059f9355/quotes.json';

    $.getJSON(link, function(data) {

      var random = data[Math.floor((Math.random() * data.length) + 1)];
      $innerhtml.animate({ //Here is the problem, its not working
          opacity: 0
        }, 500,
        function() {
          $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
          }, 1000);
          $(this).html('<p>"' + random[0] + '"</p>' + random[1]);
        });
    });
  });

});
```

```css
body.act {
  background: curentColor;
  transition: all ease-in-out 2s;
}
body.die {
  background: curentColor;
  transition: all ease-in-out 2s;
}
.wrapper {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.btn {
  height: 40px;
}
.innerhtml.act {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20% auto 5%;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all linear 2s;
}
.innerhtml.die {
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: all lineaer 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='act'>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerhtml die"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">


    <button class="btn btn-default quote">New quote</button>

  </div>
</body>
```